# Explode a DataFrame of array<array<string>> created from json scala

Tags: scala

I have json data like:

```
{
    "resultid": "Success",
    "userId": "abc",
    "cardtype": "ag",
    "computescore": [{
        "values": ["654", "655", "666"]
    }, {
        "values": ["754", "755", "777"]
    }]
}

scala> val a = input.select("computescore.values")
a: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [values: array<array<string>>]

scala> a.collect.foreach(println) 
[WrappedArray(WrappedArray(654, 655, 666), WrappedArray(754, 755, 777))]
```

What I want to achieve from this is dataframe with multiple rows and multiple  column

for instance

```
a1     a2    a3
654    655   666
754    755   777
```

Answer (score 0):

Achieved by doing this

```
val input = sqlContext.jsonFile("D:/test.json")
val a = input.select("computescore.values")

val b=a.explode("values","mvnew"){test: WrappedArray[WrappedArray[String]]    => test.asInstanceOf[WrappedArray[WrappedArray[String]]]}
val c=b.select("mvnew")
val d=c.map {case Row(col2: WrappedArray[String]) => (col2(0), col2(1), col2(2))}.toDF( "Col2", "Col3", "Col4")
```

Is there a better way to do this

Answer (score 0):

val sortDates = udf { arr: collection.mutable.WrappedArray[Row] =>
  arr.map { 
    case Row(a: String, b: String, c: String, d: String, e : String, f: Long, g:String, h:Integer) =>
            (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h) 
  }.sortBy(_._4) 
}